# VS Code "Clone Repository" button is disabled

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, repository

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSQsI.png)
My VS Code "Clone Repository" button"Clone Repository" button is always grey out and can not be clicked.
I am using MacOS.

I have tried to reinstall VS Code but the button is still disabled.
I have git installed.
Remote repository is working but clone is not.

Comment: That button gets enabled when git extension is activated. Some more info will be needed to figure out what went wrong. 
1. Do you have any other git extension installed (like GitLense)?
2. Did you modify any git related config?
3. What is the output from Log (git) and Log (GitHub Authentication)?
4. How is your system git configured? (user, email etc.)

Try to see the Logs in output tab and you might find some error there that is causing this.

Comment: Reinstall `VSCode` and all things will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the issue with the following process:

- Go to: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
- Run: unins000.exe
- Delete dir: C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Code
- Delete dir: C:\Users.vscode
- Install VSC

Comment: Thanks Yaser, I forgot to mention I am using MacOs

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway, I think the solution to the problem is reinstallation. Of course, you must delete the temporary files that remain in the system for the previous installation.